# How to clear HttpAuthRequest credentials

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an app that logs users into websites that have an authentication popup using webView.

The problem comes when logging in and then going back to log in with different credentials, causing to skip HttpAuthRequest and therefore being logged in with the first credentials

What should I do?

Comment: what version of WebView are you using? (use the androidx one if you aren't already)

Comment: I just use import android.webkit.WebView;

Comment: You should use it, recommended: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/package-summary

Comment: Tried with it but didn't solve my problem

Comment: No I didn't think it would, but it'll solve future undiagnosed problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **I did the trick logging in like this:**

```
// Prefix http:// or https://
String prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/") + 2);

// Prefix + username +: + password + @ + url without prefix
String finalUrl = prefix + username + ":" + password + "@" + url.substring(url.indexOf("/") + 2);

webView.loadUrl( finalUrl );
```

Instead of using onReceivedHttpAuthRequest

Answer (score 0):

The below lines of code is enough for clearing the cookies of Web View

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

Happy Coding! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I also tried that and the app keeps login with the old credentials (skipping auth popup). I am doing that inside the OnDestroy()